# How to give a limit date for "new" product badge woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to limit date of appearing new product badge, i mean for example after 10 days the "new" badge won't appear, how should I fix that or which code shall I edit?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Are you still using [YITH WooCommerce Badge Management](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-badges-management/) for your woocommerce product badges?

Comment: No, I am using the default badges which come with woocommerce!